# Private NuGet server sometimes doesn't list packages

Tags: powershell, iis, nuget

He Guys,

I'm hosting a private NuGet server at our office and push packages to it everytime we build our solution. But sometimes I get the following error when trying to download te newly pushed package to my local system:

`Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'package-name-build-number'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.`

After I log into the server and browser on the file system of the nuget server (inside the ~/Packages folder), I see the package including the newly pushed version. Also when I visited the file system, suddently my local machine sees the package aswell.

Any ideas?

I'm hosting https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/hosting-packages/nuget.server locally on a Windows 2012 R2 server using IIS. (.NET framework 4.6).

Tim

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue, and it's causing no end of issues. This seems to only have started occurring after upgrading to nuget server 2.11.1.0 from my perspective.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I'm still having this problem....